# Using Spring's Future<Entity> and Async annotations

Tags: spring, design-patterns, asynchronous, spring-async

I was reading this page on how to use Spring's Asynchronous calls:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

This stems a few design questions:

1) Do you hide Asynchronous capabilities behind abstractions, or do you use them directly?

2) In the example link above, the code had a "while loop" checking each 10ms if each Async call had returned. Are there other ways to implement this, then an ongoing "while" loop? :) Doesn't feel very efficient...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering to question number 2: Java Future interface has only two methods: `get()` which is blocking asynchronous request until it's done and `isDone()` which checks if results are ready to show. Unfortunetely, there is no bridge between them - you cannot receive an event or another trigger informing you, that task has been calculated.

Java 8 introduced mechanizm called `CompletableFuture`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

From docs:

> A Future that may be explicitly completed (setting its value and
>   status), and may be used as a CompletionStage, supporting dependent
>   functions and actions that trigger upon its completion.

Complementary tutorial here: http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html

Answer (score 0):

1) In my experience, asynchronous capabilities are used directly. Clients need to be aware that a response is not immediately available, so they can utilize the API to wait for one. This leads to...

2) Polling. No, it's not efficient; but it is a common approach to handling asynchronous communication. Another approach would be a callback or event-based mechanism, but I've not seen that implemented in a ReST API.

- Note that [HTTP](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is designed to support polling. In the case of an asynchronous operation, a server would return 202 (Accepted). The body of a 202 response may contain a link to another endpoint, which can be polled for status updates. The status check endpoint would return 303 when the asynchronous processing has completed (or 404 in the meantime).

Comment: Sorry, I was actually a bit unclear. So a Client calls a service. The service business logic component performs several calls to backend systems, asynchronously in parallel. This is why I am wondering if I should have a loop that checks that all asynchronous calls have returned, before returning to the calling Client.

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).